# How is 0 distinguished from other integers when initializing nullptr_t?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

As I understand, `std::nullptr_t` can be initialized from `nullptr` as well as from `0`. But at the same time the third initialization below doesn't work, despite `5` has the same type as `0`:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::nullptr_t null1=0;
    std::nullptr_t null2=nullptr;
    std::nullptr_t null3=5; // error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’ in initialization
}
```

How does this work? I.e. how does the standard library distinguish `0` from `5` at compilation time, if these literals aren't template arguments?

Can one create a custom class which would similarly distinguish arguments of its constructor at compilation time, not using `std::nullptr_t` for this?

Comment: This question basically is: "Why do `-a` and `b-a` work, but `/a` not while `b/a` works?". Because the meaning of a token depends on it's context.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `nullptr_t` can be only assigned the value `nullptr` or `0` which is implicitly converted.

According to N4296 (page.86):

> **4.10    Pointer conversions**
>
> A *null pointer constant* is an **integer literal** with value **zero**
>   or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be
>   converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of
>   that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object
>   pointer or function pointer type. [...] A null pointer constant of
>   integral type can be **converted** to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

You can **not** create a similar type within C++ yourself.

`std::nullptr_t` is implemented as a **built-in** type and its distinct properties are enforced by the compiler.

---

*EDIT: Fixed  paragraph on built-in types. Thanks Yakk!*

Comment: That quote doesn't allow the mentioned conversion as `std::nullptr_t` is not a pointer type.

Comment: @TartanLlama added one additional sentence from the quoted paragraph. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 11):

> `N3337 [conv.ptr]/1:` **A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>   zero** or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the
>   result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or
>   function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion. Two null pointer values of the
>   same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is
>   a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion. **A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.**

`0` is a null pointer constant of integral type, so it can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. `5` is not a null pointer constant, so it can't be.

Answer (score 11):

> how does the standard library distinguish 0 from 5 at compilation time, if these literals aren't template arguments?

This has nothing to do with the standard library at all, `nullptr_t` is a built-in type known to the compiler, and obviously the compiler knows the difference between `5` and `0`

> Can one create a custom class which would similarly distinguish arguments of its constructor at compilation time, not using `std::nullptr_t` for this?

In general no.

You can write a type that can be initialized from `0` and not from `5` by making it take an argument of a pointer type, because `0` is a valid null pointer constant but `5` is not. But you couldn't write a type that can be constructed from `3` and not from `5`, or anything else like that.